# Form retaining textBox values - Reset?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a form the checks that several textBox's aren't null. If either of them are, it is supposed to show a message box, reset the text boxes and let the user try again. I believe i'm checking the textbox wrong. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
    public void ShowPaths()
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == null | textBox2.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Project Name and Number");
        }
        else
        {
            sm.projNumber = textBox1.Text;
            sm.projName = textBox2.Text;

            textBox3.Text = sm.Root("s");
            textBox4.Text = sm.Root("t");
        }
        textBox1.ResetText();
        textBox2.ResetText();           
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong for two reasons

```
if (textBox1.Text == null | textBox2.Text == null)
```

1. A textbox.Text is never null when you read it, it's an empty string
2. You are using the bitwise OR operator `|` when you should use the logical `||`

so the correct line is

```
if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox(......);

    // See the comment below
    textBox1.ResetText();    
    textBox2.ResetText();   
}
```

From your question is not clear if you want to reset the textbox in case of error or if you want to reset always as you do now. If you want to reset only in case of error move the two ResetText inside the if block

Comment: Hello. I've tried ResetText() but for me is not working. I'm using VB2010 express. It has resettext method but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

WinForms Texboxes never show `null` in my experience, instead returning `String.Empty`.

You can use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) to check for either case.  If you're using .Net 4, you can use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) which will return true for spaces as well.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  if (textBox1.Text == null || textBox2.Text == null)
```

instead of

```
  if (textBox1.Text == null | textBox2.Text == null)
```

You are not using `OR (||)` operator correctly.

Use `String.IsNullorEmpty(string)` to check for NULL and blank values in string variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((textBox1.Text == String.Empty) || (textBox2.Text == String.Empty))
```

if Textbox1 is empty OR textbox2 is empty (note the || instead of |)
Also the Text property is never null. It is always a string, but it could be empty (String.Empty or "")

Answer (score 0):

The .Text property of a TextBox will never be null. What you are looking for is an empty string, so:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || textBox2.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
```

or

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
```

or

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
```

The `|` operator should be a `||` as well. But this is only part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not conviced a textbox can have a null value I use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    //...
}
```